# Custom "cookie solution"

Tags: html, javascript, css, cookie, eu-cookie-law

I'm working on a website for a client who owns a restaurant.

I've just finished developing it and I'm working on the part relating to the privacy policy and related cookies.

The cookies used by the page are (identified by iubenda):

- Google Maps widget
- Google Fonts
- Font Awesome
- Cloudflare

I was wondering, is it possible to create your own "cookie solution"? or do I have to rely on services like iubenda?

Because to have full management of banners etc... on iubenda you need to be a subscriber, when I could easily manage by myself.

In a nutshell, what I've done so far is to make the banner and/or the preferences button disappear/appear and hide/show the Google Maps widget based on the user's choice.

I don't know how to behave in these cases and around the web there isn't much that explains it clearly

For this reason I would appreciate an answer that will help me to understand how to behave in the future as well.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can answer me.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking about cookies or a privacy devlaration page?

Comment: Why not use HTML5 local data storage?

Comment: I believe you're asking if you need to use a third-party service such as OneTrust or Iubenda or can you create your own cookie consent management? The simple response would be people use a service because it's a complex problem. But like anything, with the right skill and desire, you can build your own.

Comment: @Pete Yes, I tried to manage this part independently, in practice I made sure that initially the google maps are '''display: none''' and then based on the user's choice in the banner, it is shown, or not.

Comment: @Pete As for Google Fonts and Font Awesome, I created a page accessible from the footer or from the banner that mentions the  Cookie Policy, where they are "explained"

Comment: @Pete Obviously, after having accepted/refused, the user can change his choice by pressing a button that I have inserted at the bottom right of the page in '''position: fixed'''

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.  Cookies is simply a variable/token which is passed between the web client and the server so the server knows who it is talking to.  If you use Google properties then Google will want to set cookies and short of very dodgy proxying solutions (which will likely break anyway, and are probably against Googles T&C's) you can't overcome this in many cases.

When showing the Google Maps Widget you can't really overcome this and still use interactive Google maps.  Questions of legality aside you could take a static image of the map (or use Openstreetmap).  You may well be able to bypass showing Google Maps based on a user preference, but you need to make sure that the code called on your page to run Google is not sent to the browser unless the client consents.

For Google Fonts and Cloud Awesome, replace the fonts with ones you host on your own servers.

Cloudflare will probably require cookies unless you let people connect to your website directly.